# I cant store data to DB

Tags: laravel

I can´t store data, i have no errors, i tried things like changing name to id in the forms but it dosent change anything.

This is my view, is not everything but almost every select is like this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('MatchController@store') }}">

    <select class="col-sm-2 form-control" name="users1" required>

      @foreach($users1 as $users1)
        @if ($users1->id == 0 or $users1->id == Auth::user()->id);
        @else
        <option selected value="{{$users1->nick}}">{{$users1->nick}}  </option> 

        @endif
      @endforeach

    </select>

<textarea rows="4" cols="50" class=" form-control" name="text" form="usrform">Deporte, condiciones, reglas, puntuación...</textarea><hr>
</form>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Enviar') }}</button>
```

This is my controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'users1' => 'required',
            'text' => 'required',

            ]);

            $vs = new Vs;
            $vs->users1 = $request->input('users1');
            $vs->text = $request->input('text');
            $vs->save();

            return redirect('/place');
    }
```

Comment: You should put the submit button within your `<form>` tag not outside of it.

Comment: And where do you try to save something? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase how i debug? sorry im new. Im trying to save it to "vs" table

Comment: Well, you could start by checking which parts of that controller are executed (for example by using `var_dump`). Then you could inspect whatever that `save` method does

Comment: try to do `dd($request->all())` to check if data is comming or not

Comment: @KashyapMerai it takes all the data that i insert

Comment: Point of doing that is to just check if actual data is submitted or not.

Comment: so if all the data is shown it means that the data is submited?, i dont know if the problem could be the routes.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add `{{ csrf_field() }}` field in your form.

Here is the form with `{{ csrf_field() }}` field. Can you try with this ?

```
 <form method="POST" action="{{ action('MatchController@store') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
        <select class="col-sm-2 form-control" name="users1" required>

          @foreach($users1 as $users1)
            @if ($users1->id == 0 or $users1->id == Auth::user()->id);
            @else
            <option selected value="{{$users1->nick}}">{{$users1->nick}}  </option> 

            @endif
          @endforeach

        </select>

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class=" form-control" name="text" form="usrform">Deporte, condiciones, reglas, puntuación...</textarea><hr>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Enviar') }}</button>  
</form>
```

Comment: added but it keeps the same

Comment: If an issue is in `CSRF` Laravel throws `419 Unknown Status`

Answer (score 0):

you didn't use csrf token in your form you can use this

```
    <form method="POST" action="{{ action('MatchController@store') }}">
 <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
<select class="col-sm-2 form-control" name="users1" required>

  @foreach($users1 as $users1)
    @if ($users1->id == 0 or $users1->id == Auth::user()->id);
    @else
    <option selected value="{{$users1->nick}}">{{$users1->nick}}  </option> 

    @endif
  @endforeach

</select>
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? What makes you think that this token is needed? As the OP stated in the other answer one hour older than your's (another user recommended to add the CSRF token), he did add the token field, but that did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

In blade file:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ action('MatchController@store') }}">

    @csrf

    <select class="col-sm-2 form-control" name="users1" required>

        @foreach($users1 as $users1)
            @if ($users1->id == 0 or $users1->id == Auth::user()->id);
            @else
                <option selected value="{{$users1->nick}}">{{$users1->nick}}  </option> 
            @endif          
        @endforeach

    </select>

    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" class=" form-control" name="text" form="usrform">Deporte, condiciones, reglas, puntuación...</textarea><hr>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">{{ __('Enviar') }}</button>
</form>
```

In controller:

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'users1' => 'required',
        'text' => 'required',
    ]);

    $post = $request->all();

    Vs::create($post);

    return redirect('/place');
}
```